# Connection with API - redux

Tags: php, laravel-5, fetch, react-redux

I'm building a project with react and redux, but I can't connect with my `API`.
I have this,

```
componentDidMount() {
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    dispatch(fetchByQuerystring());
}
```

and `fetchByQuerystring` is:

```
export function fetchByQuerystring() {
    return function(dispatch) {

        return fetch(`http://my_domain.dev/api`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => dispatch(receiveByQuerystring(json)));
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> Fetch API cannot load http://my-domain.dev/api. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are on a site A and call (with ajax requests) a different server B ([different port, different domain name / ip address or different protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)), the browser expects B to explicitly allow A.
This is done with HTTP reponse headers added by the server B (and `OPTIONS` support), see [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

If you must be able to call your API from other servers in production, adding [CORS support in laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) is a good idea. Don't add them if you don't need them.

If your API calls are [simple enough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests) and [don't require cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials), you can configure your local Apache to just [add the header](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Otherwise, you should serve both resources (API and react frontend) from the same origin.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set CORS headers on your local webserver that runs http:/my-domain.dev/api

Headers to send: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my-domain.dev/api`

This may help for Laravel [github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors](http://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)